# SSIS For Loop container - How to iterate over certain dates till certain date value

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, expression, control-flow

I am creating an SSIS package with `For Loop container` to load archived data for past years.

Actual scenario is - The data needs to be loaded based on each month end date starting `2013-01-31` till today or certain month end date (i.e. 2013-06-30)

I have put my data flow task inside For Loop container which reads few source tables to create a derived dataset and loads it into one destination table.

For Loop editor looks like below.
[image: For Loop Editor]

**InitExpression:** A user defined variable `Counter` is initiated with initial month end date `MEdate`

**EvalExpression:** Another user defined variable `CurrentMED` is set certain month end date (i.e. `2013-06-30`). And this EvalExpression runs till the `Counter` reads `2013-06-30`.

**AssignExpression:** `Counter` increments or supposed to read through the next month end date.

The `MEdate` value is passed into data flow task and applies to SQL queries to retrieve data.

**Real Issue:** When the package runs, it reads the first month end date correctly but and load data from source table to destination table correctly. But then after the loop runs infinitely. It does not read the next month end date. It keeps loading data from source to destination tables for the same date (in this case `2013-01-31`). The loop never ends the package execution.

I suspect I have 2 major issue with `AssignExpression`. As it is not

> changing and/or incrementing the next month end date

> and assigning to the variable `Counter`?

I appreciate any suggestions to resolve this.